# Why can't I install my 2.3.1 project on a 2.2.1 device?

Tags: android

Please have a little patience with me.  I have been going through the Dev Guide on andriod.com and I have went through some of the tutorials. For example I have gone through the Hello World app, everything seems fine.  I went a head and used the ADT export to export a signed packaged that I used the debug key to sign the apk file.  I copied the apk to my android device and all I get when I try to run it is a could not parse error.  It works fine on the virtual devices.  My device is an Archos70 running android 2.2.1.

Now I just noticed that my project is for Android 2.3.1, could that be the issue?  Its so simple of an app I would think that really affect it would it?

Answer (score 3):

pYes, that's the issue. Downgrade to former API version. And set in your manifest.xml  minimum version of Android OS.

Edit: How you set minimum SDK version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.package.name"
     android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="VERSION-NUMBER-GOES-HERE-e.g: 7 or 8 etc" />
```

Comment: How do I set the minimum version in the manifest.xml, I don't see that option.

Comment: nvrmnd I just recreated the project lot quick than trying to modify the original I had.  Thx for the help that seemed to work!  Didn't realize it was that touchy

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your minSdk version to smaller for example to 4 in your manifest file. Hope that it helps.